# AWS Cloudformation "Include" transform issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

AWS Cloudformation defines **Transform** section on global template level as an array.
See Transform section definition [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html).

I created two entries in **Transform** section that include some partial definitions of stack resources.
The goal is to create a few files with definitions/resources grouped by "product domain" per file.

When I create stack based on this template it executes one partial definition only (the last one - other definitions with "AWS::Include" name are ignored or "overridden")

This is the main template definition:

```js
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

  "Description": "Test of json file inclusion",

  "Parameters": {
    "Environment": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Specify Environment: prod | dev ",
      "AllowedValues": ["prod", "dev"],
      "Default": "dev"
    }
  },

  "Transform": [
    {
      "Name": "AWS::Include",
      "Parameters": {
        "Location": "s3://a1-local/cf-tests/part-1.json"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "AWS::Include",
      "Parameters": {
        "Location": "s3://a1-local/cf-tests/part-2.json"
      }
    }
  ],

  "Outputs": {
  }
}
```

This is part-1 definition

```js
{
  "Mappings": {
      "MappingForBucket1": {
        "eu-west-1": { "AZs": [ "eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b" ] }
      }
  },

  "Resources": {
    "hellobucket1": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "BucketName": { "Fn::Sub": "as-testbucket1-${Environment}" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is part-2 definition

```js
{
  "Mappings": {
      "MappingForBucket2": {
        "eu-west-1": { "AZs": [ "eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b" ] }
      }
  },

  "Resources": {
    "hellobucket2": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "BucketName": { "Fn::Sub": "as-testbucket2-${Environment}" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How to join/chain multiple transformations in such case?**

Comment: Hi Liam, if I define Include transform on resource level it means I can create json file with resource definitions only (anyway I can include such file once only also in such case). I can't create many files with separate resource definitions and include all of them on resource level with many Include transforms. I need it on global level because usually I'd like to define Resources and Mappings related to them in the same file...

Comment: Okay yeah understood, let me dig some more :) It seems this was an issue back in 2017 but I assume that AWS has definitely fixed it now, can you look at this and see if it will resolve your issue: https://medium.com/@antonf_70246/aws-cloudformation-transforms-and-multiple-mappings-6475b332da3c It looks like using mappings may be the way to go.

Comment: The main issue is I'd like to create a few files with a few resource definitions inside (and related mappings for instance)

Comment: Okay check above and see if that works for you.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work in such case. It looks cf creates some dictionary from  elements on Transforms array so it's impossible to create elems without providing Name attribute. If you provide something else then AWS::Include in name - cf assumes it's lambda :(

Comment: Yes however if you use mappings then you can give them a logical id like `"bucket1/2"` and also keep the "Name": "AWS::Include" part of the Template so that cloudformation doesn't get confused.

Comment: In case of mappings I can provide any texts as attributes (on proper levels). In case of Transforms, Resources etc json schema defines what is obligatory so I can't define Transforms array element without Name attribute for instance :(
If I provide AWS::Include text on name attribute many time the result is as described above. If you were thinking about something else just let me know...

Comment: To be honest I don't see any workaround for such issue at the moment :(
The main problem is such simple definition should not lose any array elements I provide when schema defines it as an array! :)